# Boostrap div content align center?

Tags: python, html, flask, web-applications

i am making a web app with bootstrap and i want to put my div content to the center of the page and the table with it so i need help. Here is my code and preview of the page below. Thanks in advance!

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}<title>{{ title }}</title>{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section bg-white border border-primary mx-md-n5 shadow-lg px-5 mt-auto">
        <form method='POST' action=''>
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-3">Calculate BMI</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.weight.label(class="form-control-label mb-3") }}
                    {% if form.weight.errors %}
                        {{ form.weight(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.weight.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.weight(class='form-control form-control-lg') }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.height.label(class="form-control-label mb-3") }}
                    {% if form.height.errors %}
                        {{ form.height(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.height.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.height(class='form-control form-control-lg') }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-danger btn-block")}}
                </div>
                <small><i>Formula: [Weight(kg)/Height²(cm²)] * 10000</i></small>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr class="border border-primary shadow-lg mx-md-n5">
    <table class="table table-responsive-md mx-md-n5 shadow-lg table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
            <th scope="col">Table</th>
            <th scope="col">Low Body Weight</th>
            <th scope="col">Normal Weight</th>
            <th scope="col">Overweight</th>
            <th scope="col">Adipositas</th>
            <th scope="col">Too Overweight</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">BMI:</th>
            <td> < 19 </td>
            <td>19-24</td>
            <td>25-29</td>
            <td>30-40</td>
            <td> > 40 </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


{% endblock %}
```

HERE IS A LINK TO A PICTURE OF THE PAGE!
[PREVIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkhwZ.png)

I tried to fix that but i just can't . I must've done something wrong even though i checked the docs of the Bootstrap as well...

Comment: Did you try adding a `.justify-content-center` on the main `div`? If I were you, I'd wrap everything in a `.container`or`.container-fluid` and then a `.row` (specify the amount of `.col`'s) and add `.justify-content-center` on the `.row` and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

To make any content center aligned  in bootstrap I always use very basic trick. No matter which  you are using just write **text-center** in value of **class attribute**. If you are already using any other class simply enter **text-center** next to it.

For example. Refer following snippet.

```
<div class="content-section text-center">
```

Also you can use bootstrap grid systems i.e. row and col classes to align the contents as per your requirements.

Hope you will

Comment: I believe they're looking for the whole `div` to be centered on the page, not the content to be centered inside the `div`

Comment: Yes i was looking for the whole div to be centered and i've figured it out , thank you for all your support from both of you !